# Microsoft Band Cloud API Steps

Tags: microsoft-band

If I look at the Microsoft health website, for a given day (8/23/2015) it shows Total Steps taken as **10,058**. If I call the API with:

`Summaries/DailystartTime=2015-08-23T00:00:00.0000000Z&endTime=2015-08-24T00:00:00.0000000Z`

it returns:

> {"summaries":[{"userId":"removed","startTime":"2015-08-23T00:00:00.000+00:00","endTime":"2015-08-24T00:00:00.000+00:00","period":"Daily","duration":"P1D","stepsTaken":**12986**,".....

Why the difference in stepsTaken? 10,058 vs 12,986

Answer (score 1):

the timezone you're in might be different than UTC. The returned data is for UTC range.